# How to add dynamic field into DB Lavavel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-5

I am having problems to add dynamic field into database, If I return all values I get values entered however if I try to add into database I get 500 error. 
this is my dynamic field:

```
    var i = 1;
    $('#add_field').click(function(){
   i++;
   $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td class="col-md-5"><textarea class="name borders table-control" type="text" rows="1" cols="45" name="name[]"></textarea></td><td class="col-md-2"><input class="borders table-control price" type="text" name="price[]"></td><td class="col-md-2"><input class="borders table-control qty" type="text" name="qty[]"></td><td class="col-md-2"><input class="form-control total" type="text" name="total[]"></td><td class="text-center"><span id="'+i+'" style="color: red" name="remove" class="btn_remove"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></td></tr>');

});
```

This is my Ajax call:

```
$(document).on('change','.qty',function(){


    var id = $("#inv_id").val();
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var name = tr.find(".name").val(); 
    var price = tr.find(".price").val(); 
    var qty = tr.find(".qty").val(); 
    var total = tr.find(".total").val(); 

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/product',
        data: {'id': id, 'name': name, 'price': price, 'qty': qty, 'total': total, '_token':$('input[name=_token]').val()},
        success: function( data ) {

            console.log(data);

        },
            error: function(data){
            alert("fail");

            }
    });
});
```

And here is my controller:

```
public function product(Request $request){

    $products = $request->all();

      $id = $products['id'];
      $name = $products['name'];
      $price = $products['price'];
      $qty = $products['qty'];
      $total = $products['total'];

     for( $i = 0; $i < count($name); $i++) {


            $prod = new Product();
            $prod->invoice_id = $id;
            $prod->name = $name[$i];
            $prod->price = $price[$i];
            $prod->qty = $qty[$i];
            $prod->total = $total[$i];
            $prod->save();

     }   


    return response()->json($prod->toArray(), 200);

}
```

this is my product model

```
 protected $fillable = [ 'invoice_id', 'name', 'qty', 'price', 'total' ];
```

I have tried Product::create($request->all), actually i have tried everything I know. thats why I need you help guys.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157032/discussion-between-ljubadr-and-denisson-de-souza).

Comment: @ljubadr, i finally managed to fix the code. My code was fine, all i had to do it was refresh the page. so simple but took me long time. oh well I am learning. will post here the code.

Answer (score 0):

all i had to do it was refresh the page.

```
public function product(Request $request){
$prod = new Product();
$prod->invoice_id = $request->id;
$prod->name = $request->name;
$prod->price = $request->price;
$prod->qty = $request->qty;
$prod->total = $request->total;
$prod->save();
 return response()->json($prod->toArray(), 200);
}

$(document).on('change','.qty',function(){

    var name = [];
    var price = [];
    var qty = [];
    var total = [];


    var id = $("#inv_id").val();
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    name = tr.find(".name").val(); 
    price = tr.find(".price").val(); 
    qty = tr.find(".qty").val(); 
    total = tr.find(".total").val(); 


    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/product',
        data: {id: id, name: name, price: price, qty: qty, total: total, '_token':$('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
        success: function( data ) {
            $('#form').load(location.href + ' #form');
            location.reload();
        }

    });
});
```